# Doublespace environment behaving oddly and I have no idea way

Tags: spacing, setspace

I am a high school teacher looking to replicate the formatting of a common exam using TeX - to try and make this easier on myself, I'm trying to write commands that will let me mimic common questions. I am currently having some problems with the doublespace environment - the formatting uses double-spacing to create question lines. Here's a working example of me implementing this:

```
\newcounter{qnumber}
\newcounter{partnumber}[qnumber]
\newcommand{\writeq}[3][0]{ %simple written question command
    \stepcounter{qnumber}
    \textbf{Question \arabic{qnumber}\hfill (#2 marks)}\\
    #3\\
    \begin{doublespace}
        \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\\}
    \end{doublespace}    
}

\writeq[3]{4}{My question is this one.}
```

[image]

So, I now want to create "multi-part questions", and have constructed the following command:

```
%Multi-part question commands
\newcommand{\mpqstem}[2]{
    \stepcounter{qnumber}
    \setcounter{partnumber}{0}  % Reset part number
    \noindent \textbf{Question \arabic{qnumber}\hfill (#1 marks)}\\ \\ 
    #2 \vspace{0.2cm}
}

\newcommand{\mpq}[3][0]{ %simple written question command
    \stepcounter{partnumber}
    \alph{partnumber}) \hangindent=1.27cm \hangafter=0 #3\\
    \rule{0pt}{1pt}\hfill(#2 marks)\vspace{0.5cm}
    \begin{doublespace}
        \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{\rule{\linewidth-1.27cm}{0.5pt}\\}
    \end{doublespace} 
}
```

The stem is used to set the context, and the mpq command is then the actual question related to that part. However, using this combination, I'm getting the text to be doublespaced but not the lines - and I cannot figure out why. See below me attempting to use the command and what I'm getting out:

```
\mpqstem{4}{This is the scary question, and thankfully this bit is showing up okay without any double-spacing. But that also makes sense, since this command doesn't touch the spacing.}

\mpq[2]{2}{This is part 1, and it's going to be very long to show what is happening with the spacing and make it clear that this is double-spaced.}

\mpq[2]{2}{This is part 2, and it's also going to be very long to show what is happening with the spacing and make it clear that this is double-spaced.}
```

[image]

Comment: You didn't provide a full example that can be tested, but double spacing is a setting that affect *paragraphs*, and paragraphs should be separated by empty lines or `\par`  and not by ``\\``. Stop to use all these ``\\`` everywhere, (and never use ``\\ \\ `` to create space).

Comment: Note also, that `\vspace` is *not* an end of paragraph. So, you may also need additional `\par` at this place. But without [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) I cannot test, if this is relevant in your case.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks so much! Apologies also my MWE was incomplete - I was in a rush and completely forgot to include my packages and variables. 

\par has fixed the inconsistency - was trivial to get things working as intended after that. Also can't believe I missed the missing \par, thanks for pointing that out as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code snippet is not compilable since it lacks a lot of crucial information. For sure, though, do take @UlrikeFischer's suggestion to heart and stop using `\\` instead of `\par`. E.g., for the three commands, the following code may be helpful in terms of achieving your ultimate formatting goals.

```
\newcounter{qnumber}
\newcounter{partnumber}[qnumber] tie 'partnumber' counter to 'qnumber' counter

\newcommand{\writeq}[3][0]{ %simple written question command
    \refstepcounter{qnumber} % use \refstepcounter, not \stepcounter
    \par\noindent
    \textbf{Question \arabic{qnumber}\hfill(#2 marks)}
    \par
    #3
    \par
    \begin{doublespace}
        \foreach \n in {1,\dots,#1}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}}
        \par
    \end{doublespace}
}

\newcommand{\mpqstem}[2]{
    \refstepcounter{qnumber}
    %%\setcounter{partnumber}{0}  % not needed
    \par\noindent 
    \textbf{Question \arabic{qnumber}\hfill(#1 marks)}
    \par
    \vspace{1\baselineskip}
    #2 
    \par
    \vspace{2mm}
}

\newcommand{\mpq}[3][0]{ %simple written question command
    \refstepcounter{partnumber}
    \par\noindent \hangindent=1.27cm \hangafter=0
    \alph{partnumber}) #3
    \par\noindent
    \rule{0pt}{1pt}\hfill(#2 marks)
    \par
    \vspace{5mm}
    \begin{doublespace}
        \foreach \n in {1,\dots,#1}{\rule{\linewidth-1.27cm}{0.5pt}}
        \par
    \end{doublespace} 
}
```

Comment: Using \par has fixed everything suitably - also thank you for all the extra help! Reading over this is showing a lot of ways I can improve what I've currently got, will definitely be implementing a few of these fixes!